# PHP PDO installation on windows (xampp)

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, sybase

I am trying to develop a web app that can connect to as many different databases as possible on PHP. PDO (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) seems to be the right interface for it but I am having trouble installing all the extentions needed for all the different PDO database drivers that I need.

Please note that I use xampp on a windows 7 machine. PHP Version 5.3.8. PDO drivers enabled mysql, odbc, sqlite, sqlite2, sqlsrv.

I have successfully connected with the following:

- **MySQL** using **PDO_MYSQL** [MySQL (PDO) ] (extension seemed to be installed on xampp by default)
- **Microsoft SQL Server** using **PDO_SQLSRV** [MS SQL Server (PDO)] (followed the instractions on http://craigballinger.com/blog/2011/08/usin-php-5-3-with-mssql-pdo-on-windows/)

I had no luck installing or connecting with:

- (SOLVED SEE BELOW UPDATES) **Sybase** (I tried to use and install **PDO_DBLIB** [MS SQL Server (PDO)]but with no luck)
- (SOLVED SEE BELOW UPDATES)**Oracle** (I tried to enable the extension=php_pdo_oci.dll in php.ini with the dll that was installed with xampp after restarting Apache the server failed to start. Was trying to use **PDO_OCI** [Oracle (PDO)])

I know I can work around those 2 with using the database specific drivers but I would really love to use PDO for everything that I need.

Does anyone know how to install and enable **PDO_DBLIB** and **PDO_OCI**  drivers or a windows machine, or any other way of connecting with Sybase and Oracle databases using PDO?

---

**UPDATE**

Just succesfully connected with **oracle** with **PDO_OCI**. What you need to do is the following:

> Download and install the proper Oracle Instant Client on your windows machine for
>   example instantclient_12_1 and add its path to PATH in SYSTEM
>   Environmental Variables. Note Oracle supports only 2 versions down so select
>   your client version properly. Do that and then restart your Apache. Note that the connection string is very different from here is a sample of what I used:

```
$tns = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ".$myServer.")(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=".$myDB.")))"; 
$connStr = "oci:dbname=".$tns;      
$conn = new PDO($connStr,$myUser,$myPass);
```

---

**UPDATE**

Just connected with **Sybase** as well with **PDO_ODBC**. What you need is the following:

> Must have Sybase ASE ODBC Driver which comes with the SDK. Find below the connection string used:

```
$connStr = "odbc:Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise};server=".$myServer.";port=".$myPort.";db=".$myDB;
$conn = new PDO($connStr,$myUser,$myPass);
```

Comment: May I ask *why* do you want to connect to as many different databases as possible?

Comment: sure, am trying to gather information from different systems to be displayed into one place. sort of like a portal to monitor error tables and some statistics.

Comment: Updated my post with the solution for connecting with oracle and  PDO_OCI. If anyone has a solution for sybase as well please let us know

Comment: Updated my post with the solution for connecting with Sybase. PDO_ODBC used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i finally managed to connect to four database here's how I managed:

---

**MySQL** using **PDO_MYSQL** extension seemed to be installed on xampp by default didn't have to do much work. Here is the code I used for the connection:

```
$connStr = "mysql:host=".$myServer.";dbname=".$myDB; 
$conn = new PDO($connStr,$myUser,$myPass);
```

---

**Microsoft SQL Server** using **PDO_SQLSRV**  followed the instructions on http://craigballinger.com/blog/2011/08/usin-php-5-3-with-mssql-pdo-on-windows/. Here is the code I used:

```
$connStr = "sqlsrv:Server=".$myServer.";Database=".$myDB; 
$conn = new PDO($connStr,$myUser,$myPass);
```

---

**Oracle** with **PDO_OCI**. Download and install the proper Oracle Instant Client on your windows machine for example instantclient_12_1 and add its path to PATH in SYSTEM Environmental Variables. Note Oracle supports only 2 versions down so select your client version properly. Do that and then restart your Apache. Here is the code I used:

```
$tns = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ".$myServer.")(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=".$myDB.")))"; 
$connStr = "oci:dbname=".$tns;      
$conn = new PDO($connStr,$myUser,$myPass);
```

---

**Sybase** with **PDO_ODBC** Must have Sybase ASE ODBC Driver which comes with the SDK. Here is the code I used:

```
$connStr = "odbc:Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise};server=".$myServer.";port=".$myPort.";db=".$myDB;
$conn = new PDO($connStr,$myUser,$myPass);
```