# PHP PDO - can't see available drivers

Tags: php, pdo

I am new to php pdo and I have to connect to MySQL driver but when I try to see which driver is available with

```
print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers())
```

returns empty array.What I have to do to see that MySQL driver is available?

Comment: Are you running on Windows or Linux?

Comment: on Windows.. I installed Xampp I thing I have to put the php file in /xampp/htdoc folder but I am not sure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224729/php-pdo-installation-on-windows-xampp gives some info - but it claims that at least the mysql driver would be there.  Have a look using `phpinfo();`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue before, PDO return error message `Could not find driver`, but when I check, PDO is working fine, but has empty available drivers.

Later, I found out that the solution to my issue is, change the `c:\php` path in the system environment to `c:\xampp\php`. You might save your PHP or XAMPP in a different location, but you get the idea.

The thing is, before I use **phpMyAdmin**, I already installed a PHP on my computer, and set the system path to this PHP. But later I install XAMPP because I wanna use **MySQL**, but my system environment still runs PHP code through the old PHP path. After changing the path, the problem solved.